# MongoDB aggregate query for values in an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have data that looks like this:

```
{
   _id: 1, 
   ranking: 5, 
   tags: ['Good service', 'Clean room']
}
```

Each of these stand for a review. There can be multiple reviews with a ranking of 5. The tags field can be filled with up to 4 different tags.

4 tags are: 'Good service', 'Good food', 'Clean room', 'Need improvement'

I want to make a MongoDB aggregate query where I say 'for each ranking (1-5) give me the number of times each tag occurred for each ranking.

So an example result might look like this, _id being the ranking:

```
 [ 
   { _id: 5, 
    totalCount: 5, 
    tags: {
       goodService: 1, 
       goodFood: 3, 
       cleanRoom: 1, 
       needImprovement: 0
   }, 
   { _id: 4, 
    totalCount: 7, 
    tags: {
       goodService: 0, 
       goodFood: 2, 
       cleanRoom: 3, 
       needImprovement: 0
   }, 
   ...
]
```

Having trouble with the counting the occurrences of each tag. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$tags"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "ranking":"$ranking",
      "tags":"$tags"
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.ranking",
    "totalCount":{"$sum":"$count"},
    "tags":{"$push":{"tags":"$_id.tags","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

To get the key value pair instead of array you can replace `$push` with `$mergeObjects` from 3.6 version.

```
"tags":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id.tags","$count"]]]}}
```

Comment: So this works, except it's only bringing back the first of the rankings. I get the ranking for 1. The data looks reasonable. But I don't get info for 2,3,4 or 5.

Comment: Some of the reviews don't have tags. I might not have mentioned that

Comment: That is alright. I was able to get all rankings when I ran the query with multiple documents. Use `{"$unwind":{path:"$tags", preservenullandemptyarrays:true}}` to account for missing tags.

Comment: So almost there, the data is coming in. But I am also getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined"

I imagine this has to do with including the reviews with null ratgins. Can we get rid of that?

Comment: Giving you a point for the help so far. Thanks for sticking with me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't an issue with the query. Thank you so much!